# why my Mac disk size become zero while Mac running long time?

Tags: macos, virtual-memory

While my my Mac starts, it shows about 2GB free size but after running about 5-6 hours, I use Firefox and other apps at that time, then only leave the FF running (not close), other apps also in stop working mode I think. I close my Mac not shutdown. I do this because I am lazy to reboot my mac ... after about 5-6 hours, Mac report my disk size is full. I am confuse by this, anyone also face this type problem before?

My Mac is Mac OS X v 10.6.8.

Comment: This should probably get migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Anyhow, you could use something like [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to find out which files are taking up space.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of temporary files and pages of virtual memory were paged to RAM. I know this could take up quite a bit of space, so it's non impossible that it used up the last few gigabytes with those processes open.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your home directory encrypted it is in a sparse-bundle. This can only be shrunk when it is unmounted - that happens only when you log out. 
So if you like me keep logged in all the time it will grow till all space is used up. (and logging off takes an eternity)

btw. just 2 GB free is kinda little free space anyway.